# Detecting the end of the stream on popen.stdout.readline

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

I have a python program which launches subprocesses using `Popen` and consumes their output nearly real-time as it is produced.  The code of the relevant loop is:

```
def run(self, output_consumer):
    self.prepare_to_run()
    popen_args = self.get_popen_args()
    logging.debug("Calling popen with arguments %s" % popen_args)
    self.popen = subprocess.Popen(**popen_args)
    while True:
        outdata = self.popen.stdout.readline()
        if not outdata and self.popen.returncode is not None:
            # Terminate when we've read all the output and the returncode is set
            break
        output_consumer.process_output(outdata)
        self.popen.poll()  # updates returncode so we can exit the loop
    output_consumer.finish(self.popen.returncode)
    self.post_run()

def get_popen_args(self):
    return {
        'args': self.command,
        'shell': False, # Just being explicit for security's sake
        'bufsize': 0,   # More likely to see what's being printed as it happens
                        # Not guarantted since the process itself might buffer its output
                        # run `python -u` to unbuffer output of a python processes
        'cwd': self.get_cwd(),
        'env': self.get_environment(),
        'stdout': subprocess.PIPE,
        'stderr': subprocess.STDOUT,
        'close_fds': True,  # Doesn't seem to matter
    }
```

This works great on my production machines, but on my dev machine, the call to `.readline()` hangs when certain subprocesses complete.  That is, it will successfully process all of the output, including the final output line saying "process complete", but then will again poll `readline` and never return.  This method exits properly on the dev machine for most of the sub-processes I call, but consistently fails to exit for one complex bash script that itself calls many sub-processes.

It's worth noting that `popen.returncode` gets set to a non-`None` (usually `0`) value many lines before the end of the output.  So I can't just break out of the loop when that is set or else I lose everything that gets spat out at the end of the process and is still buffered waiting for reading.  The problem is that when I'm flushing the buffer at that point, I can't tell when I'm at the end because the last call to `readline()` hangs.  Calling `read()` also hangs.  Calling `read(1)` gets me every last character out, but also hangs after the final line.  `popen.stdout.closed` is always `False`.  How can I tell when I'm at the end?

All systems are running python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  FWIW, `stderr` is being merged with `stdout` using `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Why the difference?  Is it failing to close `stdout` for some reason?  Could the sub-sub-processes do something to keep it open somehow?  Could it be because I'm launching the process from a terminal on my dev box, but in production it's launched as a daemon through `supervisord`?  Would that change the way the pipes are processed and if so how do I normalize them?

Comment: Isn't the problem you're reading a line from a process that no longer exists?

Comment: I don't think so.  If the mistake were that simple, it would fail everywhere, all the time.

Comment: Why can you not just break on ``not outdata``

Comment: @sotapme Sure - but that doesn't change anything.  It's hanging after a `readline()` which returns a valid line.

Comment: `.poll()` returns `.returncode` i.e., you can test it directly. Add `close_fds=True` and `self.popen.stdout.close()` at the end (cleanup). What is `bufsize`? Have you tried `expect_unbuffer`, `stdbuf`, etc to prevent block-bufferring on the subprocess' side? You could try [`select`](http://ideone.com/wm4ecF).

Comment: In a similar vein to J.F. Sebastian's comment, can you add some detail about the arguments you're passing to the `Popen` constructor?

Comment: By the sounds of it, the problem isn't with the Python code, but in this "one complex bash script". Could you provide a minimal example of a script which could be used to reproduce the fault?

Comment: Focusing on the script is a good idea...

Comment: You can close the pipe (stdout + stderr) from the child bash process when its output is gone by these commands `exec 1>&-` `exec 2>&-` as I described in my aswer. I think that recommendations from the accepted answer are less robust than explicit closing the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main code loop looks right.  It could be that the pipe isn't closing because another process is keeping it open.  For example, if script launches a background process that writes to `stdout` then the pipe will no close.  Are you sure no other child process still running?

An idea is to change modes when you see the `.returncode` has set.  Once you know the main process is done, read all its output from buffer, but don't get stuck waiting.  You can use [select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) to read from the pipe with a timeout.  Set a several seconds timeout and you can clear the buffer without getting stuck waiting child process.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the contents of the "one complex bash script" which causes the problem, there's too many possibilities to determine the exact cause.

However, focusing on the fact that you claim it works if you run your Python script under `supervisord`, then it might be getting stuck if a sub-process is trying to read from stdin, or just behaves differently if stdin is a tty, which (I presume) `supervisord` will redirect from `/dev/null`.

This minimal example seems to cope better with cases where my example `test.sh` runs subprocesses which try to read from stdin...

```
import os
import subprocess

f = subprocess.Popen(args='./test.sh',
                     shell=False,
                     bufsize=0,
                     stdin=open(os.devnull, 'rb'),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                     close_fds=True)

while 1:
    s = f.stdout.readline()
    if not s and f.returncode is not None:
        break
    print s.strip()
    f.poll()
print "done %d" % f.returncode
```

Otherwise, you can always fall back to using a [non-blocking read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python), and bail out when you get your final output line saying "process complete", although it's a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 2):

If you use readline() or read(), it should not hang. No need to check returncode or poll(). If it is hanging when you know the process is finished, it is most probably a subprocess keeping your pipe open, as others said before.

There are two things you could do to debug this:
* Try to reproduce with a minimal script instead of the current complex one, or
* Run that complex script with `strace -f -e clone,execve,exit_group` and see what is that script starting, and if any process is surviving the main script (check when the main script calls exit_group, if strace is still waiting after that, you have a child still alive).

Answer (score 1):

I find that calls to `read` (or `readline`) sometimes hang, despite previously calling `poll`. So I resorted to calling `select` to find out if there is readable data. However, `select` without a timeout can hang, too, if the process was closed. So I call select in a semi-busy loop with a tiny timeout for each iteration (see below).

I'm not sure if you can adapt this to readline, as readline might hang if the final `\n` is missing, or if the process doesn't close its stdout before you close its stdin and/or terminate it. You could wrap this in a generator, and everytime you encounter a `\n` in stdout_collected, yield the current line.

Also note that in my actual code, I'm using pseudoterminals (pty) to wrap the popen handles (to more closely fake user input) but it should work without.

```
# handle to read from
handle = self.popen.stdout

# how many seconds to wait without data
timeout = 1

begin = datetime.now()
stdout_collected = ""

while self.popen.poll() is None:
    try:
        fds = select.select([handle], [], [], 0.01)[0]
    except select.error, exc:
        print exc
        break

    if len(fds) == 0:
        # select timed out, no new data
        delta = (datetime.now() - begin).total_seconds()
        if delta > timeout:
            return stdout_collected

        # try longer
        continue
    else:
        # have data, timeout counter resets again
        begin = datetime.now()

    for fd in fds:
        if fd == handle:
            data = os.read(handle, 1024)
            # can handle the bytes as they come in here
            # self._handle_stdout(data)
            stdout_collected += data

# process exited
# if using a pseudoterminal, close the handles here
self.popen.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the sdterr to STDOUT?

The real benefit of making a communicate() call on a subproces is that you are able to retrieve a tuple containining the stdout response as well as the stderr meesage.

Those might be useful if the logic depends on their succsss or failure.

Also, it would save you from the pain of having to iterate through lines. Communicate() gives you everything and there would be no unresolved questions about whether or not the full message was received

Comment: `communicate` waits for the process to terminate.  My application requires processing the output as it is produced.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a **demo** with bash subprocess that can be easy explored.
A **closed pipe** can be recognized by `''` in the output from `readline()`, while the output from an empty line is `'\n'`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['bash'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
out = []
while True:
    outdata = p.stdout.readline()
    if not outdata:
        break
    #output_consumer.process_output(outdata)
    print "* " + repr(outdata)
    out.append(outdata)
print "* closed", repr(out)
print "* returncode", p.wait()
```

---

*Example of input/output*: **Closing the pipe** distinctly **before terminating the process**. That is why **`wait()`** should be used instead of `poll()`

```
[prompt] $ python myscript.py
echo abc
* 'abc\n'
exec 1>&- # close stdout
exec 2>&- # close stderr
* closed ['abc\n']
exit
* returncode 0
[prompt] $
```

Your code did output a huge number of empty strings for this case.

---

*Example*: Fast terminated process without `'\n'` on the last line:

```
echo -n abc
exit
* 'abc'
* closed ['abc']
* returncode 0
```